# Vala reference counting and parameter passing

Tags: vala, reference-counting

After experimenting with Vala and inspecting the generated C source code i came up with the following Vala code:

```cs
class Foo : GLib.Object {
    public string baz;
}

class Main : GLib.Object {
    public static Foo foo;

    public static void bar(Foo f) {
        foo = null;
        f.baz = "Hi";
    }

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        foo = new Foo();
        bar(foo);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Inspecting the generated C code i realized that the Vala compiler didn't insert a reference count (RC) increment for *foo* when passing it to *bar*. So as far as i understand it, the first line in *bar* will decrement the RC of *foo* to 0, which in turn should free up *foo*, effectively making the passed variable *f* a dangling pointer, which is then accessed in the second line of *bar*. However, the program executes without problems, so i'm not sure whether i am missing something here or it works just by pure coincidence.
Here the generated C code for reference:

```c
void main_bar (Foo* f) {
    Foo* _tmp0_;
    gchar* _tmp1_;
    g_return_if_fail (f != NULL);
    _g_object_unref0 (main_foo);
    main_foo = NULL;
    _tmp0_ = f;
    _tmp1_ = g_strdup ("Hi");
    _g_free0 (_tmp0_->baz);
    _tmp0_->baz = _tmp1_;
}

gint main_main (gchar** args, int args_length1) {
    gint result = 0;
    Foo* _tmp0_;
    Foo* _tmp1_;
    _tmp0_ = foo_new ();
    _g_object_unref0 (main_foo);
    main_foo = _tmp0_;
    _tmp1_ = main_foo;
    main_bar (_tmp1_);
    result = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, and if you add a destructor on Foo you will see that it gets destroyed. Also valgrind says nothing. It's very weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. Only `owned` references are counted. Parameters are `unowned`, unless explicitly specified otherwise. So `f` in `bar`, is never reference counted because the caller is responsible for maintaining the reference count. Variable storage locations (class fields, stack variables, global variables) are all `owned`.

So, let's examine `main` and `bar` separately:

`main` creates an instance of `Foo`, which needs to be put somewhere. It puts it in the global variable `foo`, which owns it. There is now a single reference on the object created via `foo`. We then call `bar`, which takes a parameter `foo`. We know that `foo` already references the object and that passing it as a parameter does not require us to increment the reference unless the parameter is `owned`. Therefore, we simply pass the pointer `foo` to `bar`.

`bar` takes a parameter of type `Foo` called `f` which is does not own. It assigns null to a completely unrelated global variable called `foo`, this decrements the object's reference count, cleaning it up as necessary. It then does an assignment to a field in `f`.

To have this work “correctly” the compiler would have to 1) understand that `foo` and `f` are the same, even though you can call `bar` with any parameter, 2) know that decrementing the reference count on `foo` is slightly different from decrementing it to zero in some cases. That's just much too complex for any compiler not capable of solving the halting problem.

To make your code work as expected you have two options:

1. Assign your new object both to the global variable `foo` and a stack variable which you pass to `bar`. You now have ensured that the variable remains live through the call to `bar`.
2. Make `bar` take `owned Foo f` instead of `Foo f`. This will cause the caller to increment the reference on `foo` before passing it and `bar` to decrement the reference when it's done.

In short, it's the caller's responsibility to make sure that a variable remains live when it passes it to a method for the life-span of that method. You can imagine that gets a little more complicated when that method is `async`.

Comment: This sounds really complicated since for each method call you must consider the possibility that the called method or another thread might invalidate the object reference by nulling it. Also this use of the owned keyword should definitely be inserted into the Vala tutorial

Comment: The original question is not: "why does this crash?" but it's "why doesn't this crash?". You explained why the behavior is broken, but you didn't explain why it actually doesn't crash.

Comment: @BillAskaga, this is less of a problem if you keep things in local variables, rather than global.

Comment: @lethalman, this is a function of the GLib slab allocator, which does some of its own memory management. The block has not yet been freed back to the libc, even those it's been released into GLib's free pool. If you set the environment variable `G_SLICE=always-malloc`, Valgrind complains as expected.